# What does “spark our hidden creative streak“ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a sentence (the **bold** one) that I can't understand what the writer talks about :

> All of the objects and animals in these images have been generated by
>   a computer vision model called Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs)!
>   This is one of the most popular branches of deep learning right now.
>   **It certainly helps that they spark our hidden creative streak**!

Source : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/01/generative-models-gans-computer-vision/

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: It's not a very informative sentence, but it means "GANs stimulate the creative aspects of ourselves; this helps them become more popular".  I believe "our" refers to the community of his blog.

Comment: Which word(s) do you not understand? Do you understand "it certainly helps"? Do you know what "they" refers to in *that they spark our creative streak*

Answer (score 2):

The writer of the website asks

> Can you pick out what’s odd in the below collection of images?

Therein follows a set of eight seemingly random images ranging from a peacock to a salt cellar. *I thought* the reader had to identify the photo which had nothing in common with the other seven images but I was wrong, all the images are “odd” because they have been created artificially by machine learning systems called [GANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network).

The field of “computer vision“ nevertheless ***sparks*** (ignites, stimulates, unleashes etc.) our ***hidden creative streak***, which refers to the ability to use  imagination and intelligence in a creative, original way. Sometimes an ability (talent, gift) is said to be hidden if a person never knew they had it.

> **streak**
>   2. An element of a specified kind in someone's character.
>
> ‘there's a streak of insanity in the family’
>   ‘Lucy had a ruthless streak’
>   ‘Today's reading highlights the jealous streak in his character.’